# AFHTTPRequestOperationManager Get request failed,Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016

Tags: ios, afnetworking-2

I send a GET request to the url like this : `https://test.com/app/login?json={"user":"test@gmail.com","password":"test"}`

but return this error:

```
Error Domain=AFNetworkingErrorDomain Code=-1016 "Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain" UserInfo=0x9ad3520 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://test.com/app/login?json=%7B%22user%22:%22test@gmail.com%22,%22password%22:%22test%22%7D, AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey= { URL: https://test.com/app/login?json=%7B%22user%22:%22test@gmail.com%22,%22password%22:%22test%22%7D } { status code: 200, 

    headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=900";
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 6116;
    "Content-Type" = "text/plain; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 09:14:22 GMT";
    Expires = "Wed, 15 Jan 2014 09:29:22 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=2, max=100";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
    "Set-Cookie" = "APP-SESSION-ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; Path=/app/; HttpOnly, APP-ROUTE-ID=.app1_node2; path=/, API-ROUTE-ID=.app1_node2; path=/";
    } }

, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/plain}
```

Here is my code, and I have added percent escapes with NSUTF8StringEncoding.

```
manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id   responseObject) {

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have fixed this.

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"text/plain"];
```

Reference : [github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1586](http://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1586)

Comment: I used your code, and get other error Code=3840.
The host i check, have api response json type and text type also.
Does this cause bugs ?
Thanks